# Can I run a JUnit4 test suite by using specified maven goal only?

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, junit4

I am looking for a way of running a specified package of tests only when a specified maven goal is runned.

lets say that I have a

```
package com.myapp.test;
```

It is containing some standard JUnit tests, and I want those tests to be runned everytime someone is building the app locally or on any other environment (dev/test/preprod etc.) running `mvn clean package`

And I have a

```
package com.myapp.test.integration;
```

Which is containing integration tests. Every single test is extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`

I have created a suite:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DbUnitApplication.class) // this is the main Spring class, nothing special
@Persistent
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses("**/*Test.class")
public class DbUnitTestSuite {

}
```

and it is running the tests properly (the integration tests only, which is the expected behaviour). But what can I do to make them run when some command like this is runned:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install  -Pcitest -Pdbunit -Ddbunit.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

How can achieve it? Can I do it using some other way? This given command is a legacy before we have migrated from `TestNG` to `JUnit4`, and BEFORE we started the migration, all this looked a bit different, with an `pom.xml` entry:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dbunit</id>
        <properties>
            <dbunit.run.liquibase>true</dbunit.run.liquibase>
            <dbunit.skipped.group></dbunit.skipped.group>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And a class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DbUnitApplication.class)
@Test(groups = "dbunit") // IMPORTANT - this is TestNG's @Test annotation, NOT JUnit
public class DbunitTestParent extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @AfterMethod
    public final void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

And every single integration test extended this `DbunitTestParent` class.

Do You have any advice how to achieve it? How to skip those integration tests in a normal `mvn clean package` build, but somehow run them with a maven goal or another CLI parameters?

Comment: what exactly? do you mean mvn test? integrationTests shouldn't be executed during a mvn install, this might cause problems when working with continuous integration tools

Comment: @Stultuske I have a shallow knowledge about the CI process. I know that integration tests are running on Jenkins, with the long maven command I have provided. What I want to achieve is: I don't want the integration tests to run when a developer is running `mvn clean package` locally, and in some builds in the CI process. But I want to have the possibility to trigger the integration tests in one specific Jenkins build, preferably using a command like `mvn clean install -DrunIntegrationTests` or whatever this command should look like.

Comment: Integration tests should run via maven-failsafe-plugin and should be named like `*IT.java` than they will be executed by maven-failsafe-plugin by default. than you can simply do `mvn package` running unit tests only ...and `mvn verify` running also integration tests no property etc. needed. (@Stultuske IT's should never run in  `install` phase`).

Comment: @khmarbaise which was my point